# How to add a user for Visual Source Safe without an admin account?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I can access the location where the VSS database files allocate. I can also manipulate the users.txt file for VSS. How to How to add a user for Visual Source Safe without an admin account, but by directly manipulating the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply resetting the VSS admin password?

- http://not42.com/2005/06/16/visual-source-safe-admin-password-reset/
- http://thetrainerph.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9F717AF2A2401F0F!2809.entry

My feeling is that it's a gamble when it comes to editing files for VSS. Yes, they're just files, but what side effects could there be by taking this backdoor approach? It's an unknown quantity on what actually happens within the VSS Admin console when adding a new user. Why not just do it the right way?

Comment: Thanks. Resetting the admin password is not allowed:(

Comment: @airbi: what possible situation are you in that you cannot reset the password?

Comment: The situation is I am not the admin. Admin is OOF,I cannot wait he is back to add a user.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a local Windows account on the server named Admin? You should have free reign to add new users to VSS, apparently. That's teh suggestion on [this thread at microsoft.public.vstudio.sourcesafe from 2003](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vstudio.sourcesafe/browse_thread/thread/1080cbfdd3a16f39/86c954dd00660071%2386c954dd00660071?sa=X&oi=groupsr&start=1&num=3). Your mileage may vary, depending on version.

> If you just want to add new users, create an NT account called Admin and run
>   SourceSafe Admin as that user - no password prompt will appear!  You may
>   have to add "Use_Network_Name = Yes" to the srcsafe.ini file for this to
>   work. The only thing you can't do is change the password, because you need to know
>   the old password to do that.